# Proving continuity of $x^n$ on $ℝ$ for all natural numbers

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I am trying to prove $x^n$ is continuous on $ℝ$ for all natural numbers through the theorem:

Let $f$ :$ ℝ \to ℝ$ Then $f$ is continuous on $ℝ$ if and only if $f^{-1} (a,b)$ is an open set for every $a,b$ $\in$ $ℝ$.

It's my understanding that $f^{-1}(a,b)=x$ $\in$ $ℝ$ : $(a<f(x)<b)$. I was initially thinking that maybe I could build an ε-neighborhood around an arbitrary real number, $c$, that is a subset of $(a,b)$. Then I could somehow show that the $f(x)$ is in the neighborhood of $f(c)$. However, I worry I am making too many assumptions and I'm getting a bit lost. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It is sufficient to prove the power rule for differentiation.

Comment: I am not sure what you are allowed to assume. Let us first look at the case when $n$ is odd. Then for the function $f(x)=x^n$, $f^{-1}(a,b)=\{x|a<f(x)<b\}=\{x|a^{1/n}<x<b^{1/n}\}$, which is clearly an open interval. For even $n$, there are a few cases since $(\pm x)^n=x^n$, but you should be able to see what to do.

Comment: If $n$ is odd, then $x^n$ has a well-defined inverse over $\mathbb{R}$ and $f^{-1}(a,b) = (a^{1/n}, b^{1/n})$.

Comment: @TonyK I don't think so. Since that preimage of open intervals is open must imply that preimage of open sets is open too. Conway function seems to map every open interval onto the whole real line, but not the other way round.

Comment: @Vim: Thanks for putting me straight. I have deleted my comment.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no better method than prove pointwise (local) continuity directly. So, instead of trying to make a proof out of the theorem provided, you can just first prove that the provided theorem actually leads to the pointwise definition of continuity on $\Bbb R$, then make a proof out of the pointwise definition, which might be easier.

So we first check that your theorem is equivalent to the following:

> $f$ is continuous on $\Bbb R$ iff $f$ is continuous at each $x\in\Bbb R$.

The proof should be very straightforward that I omit it here. Next, with the local definition of continuity at hand, I think it's not hard for you to start off proving $f$ is continuous at every point, since you already showed your intuition in your question.